# How to replace a string of characters if the pattern comes from a vector?

Tags: r, regex

I would like to replace a part of a string, however, I want the match to be exact. In the case bellow I want ABC to be replaced with mytag and not A to be replaced with mytag etc.

```
mytags <- c("A","AB","ABC","B","BB","BBC","C","CB","CBC") 
x <- "I would like to replace ABC with mytag"
stri_replace_all_fixed(x,mytags,"mytag", vectorize_all=TRUE)

[1] "I would like to replace mytagBC with mytag" "I would like to replace mytagC with mytag"  "I 
would like to replace mytag with mytag"  
[4] "I would like to replace AmytagC with mytag" "I would like to replace ABC with mytag"     "I 
would like to replace ABC with mytag"    
[7] "I would like to replace ABmytag with mytag" "I would like to replace ABC with mytag"     "I 
would like to replace ABC with mytag"
```

What I would like to get is:

```
[1] "I would like to replace mytag with mytag"
```

Comment: A dupe of at least https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61580846 and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38605890

Comment: I can't understand how those are dupes.  First one is a question about filter, 2) question about corpus.  Please understand that not every question that touches upon regex is a dupe because of some pattern.  Here, the OP asked specifically why he/she is getting a different output than the expected

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here the pattern is having length greater than the vector.  So, it will replicate the length of the pattern.  Instead, we could create a single string pattern by concatenating with `|` in `str_c` and use that to replace so that it replace wherever any of those patterns are found

```
library(stringr)
str_replace_all(x, str_c("\\b(", str_c(mytags, collapse="|"), ")\\b"), "mytag")
#[1] "I would like to replace mytag with mytag"
```

---

Or another option is to pass a named vector

```
str_replace_all(x, setNames(rep("mytag", length(mytags)), 
       str_c("\\b", mytags, "\\b")))
#[1] "I would like to replace mytag with mytag"
```

The word boundary (`\\b`) makes sure that it won't match any partial string instead of a full word